# How to derive closed-form solution of this convex optimization problem

Tags: convex-optimization, closed-form, karush-kuhn-tucker

I want to find a closed-form solution for the following convex optimization problem.

$$ \begin{align} 
\min_{P_{ij}} & \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} \alpha_{ij} P_{ij} \hspace{10ex} \text{ where } \alpha_{ij} \ge 0 \\
\text{s.t.} & \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} P_{ij} \log \frac{P_{ij}}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} P_{ij} } + 2\le 0 \\
& \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} P_{ij} =1 \\
& 0 \le P_{ij} \le 1 \quad 1 \le i,j\le N
\end{align}
$$

I have written the KKT conditions, but cannot find my path forward for deriving a closed-form expresion.

Appreciate any tips.

Comment: Is the first constraint convex? Do you need positivity constraints on $P$?

Comment: Yes, the constraint is convex. Yes, because they are probabilities.

Comment: Unless they are non negative that cannot be true. Also, being probabilities does not make the problem convex.

Comment: Sorry, I added the condtion wehre the probabilities are in the range [0,1]. With this condtion, the constraint is convex.